# How to expand a vector of integers into consecutive integers in each group in r

Tags: r

I want to expand a vector of integers into consecutive integers in each group in r. Can anyone have some hints on this problem?

Below is my original dataset:

```
  x   = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8)
group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
data  = data.frame(x, group)
```

and my desired dataset is as below:

```
desired_data = data.frame(
   x  = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3))
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be easily done via `expand` from `tidyr`,

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(group) %>% 
 expand(x = full_seq(x, 1))
```

Which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 19 x 2
> # Groups:   group [3]
>    group     x
>    <dbl> <dbl>
>  1     1     1
>  2     1     2
>  3     1     3
>  4     1     4
>  5     1     5
>  6     2     1
>  7     2     2
>  8     2     3
>  9     2     4
> 10     2     5
> 11     2     6
> 12     3     1
> 13     3     2
> 14     3     3
> 15     3     4
> 16     3     5
> 17     3     6
> 18     3     7
> 19     3     8
> ```

Comment: Thanks Sotos. Your answer is very concise and useful. However this code does not work out when any group of data starts at any number greater than 1. In that case, expand can not expand x to a full sequence from 1 to the maxium number. Do you have any ideas on fixing that bug?

Comment: I have figured out that. The following code works out better when any group of x starts at a integer greater than 1.  `data %>% group_by(group) %>% expand(x = full_seq(1:max(x), 1))`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone will have a cleaner solution soon. In the meantime:

```
minVals=aggregate(data$x, by = list(data$group), min)[,2]
maxVals=aggregate(data$x, by = list(data$group), max)[,2]
ls=apply(cbind(minVals,maxVals),1,function(x) x[1]:x[2])

desired_data = data.frame(
  x  = unlist(ls),
  group = rep(unique(data$group),lapply(ls,length)))

   x group
1  1     1
2  2     1
3  3     1
4  4     1
5  5     1
6  1     2
7  2     2
8  3     2
9  4     2
10 5     2
11 6     2
12 1     3
13 2     3
14 3     3
15 4     3
16 5     3
17 6     3
18 7     3
19 8     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R solution.

```
x   = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8)
group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)

sl = split(x,group)

expanded = lapply(names(sl),function(x){
  r = range(sl[[x]])
  return(data.frame(x = seq(r[1],r[2],1),group = x))
})

do.call(rbind,expanded)
```

- split x by group which results in a named list per group
- using `lapply` on the names we can expand the integer range for each group
- finally use `do.call` to rbind the results together.